# NSURLSession and HTTP

Tags: ios, nsurlsession, swift-playground

I try use shared session to talk to a http server. In xcode playground,

```
import Foundation

var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

var url = NSURL(string: "http://api.zoomeye.org/user/login")

var _data: NSData?
var _response: NSURLResponse?
var _error: NSError?

var dataTask = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    _data = data
    _response = response
    _error = error
})

dataTask.resume()

print(_data)
print(_response)
print(_error)
```

the printed results are nil, it shouldn't be nil.

Use chrome to access the url, message in entity body is this,

```
{"url": "https://www.zoomeye.org/api/doc", "message": "request failed, the specified method was not allowed", "error": "method_not_allowed"}
```

Where are mistakes? and how to fix it?

Comment: because the completion handler is not executed yet

Comment: @BryanChen how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the code that is supposed to run when the data is available into the completion black. That's what it's for.